# Angular repeater text search doesn't update

Tags: angularjs

I have text filter on a repeater. Use this method on all my pages, but somehow on this page it doesn't update and can't seem to find the cause. Stripped it all down to only repeater and filter, but still no result. Might be the tiredness here, but who helps me out? The list with results is shown as expected.

```
<div ng-app="DienstenApp">
    <div ng-controller="DienstenController">
        <input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="zoek iets">
        <div ng-repeat="r in results| filter:searchText">
            <div id="diensten-h-dienstpost" class="rooster-rij">
                {{r.naam}} 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

1: {id: "1", naam: "Avond A", code: "AA", diensttype: "1", post: "3", ma: "1", di: "1", wo: "1", do: "1",…}
2: {id: "2", naam: "Avond B", code: "AB", diensttype: "1", post: "3", ma: "1", di: "1", wo: "1", do: "1",…}

$http.post('crud.php', data).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.results = data;
                    });
```

Comment: so when you enter 2 nothing happens? or the list dissappears ? did you check the console?

Comment: What are you typing in the field, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: well, everything works okay ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lewj2LWuTY5nsBSWPPk?p=preview)). type `b` and result will be filtered.

Comment: I expect the result of ieaglles example. Typing anything should update the list and remove results. Console doesn't show any errors, still it doesn't update. Nothing happens. The no error thing is annoying ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seemed to be a javascript problem. Angular code is cool, but javascript failed on this particular page. Thanks for the feedback!